# count the frequency of the elements in a list and I must print these element in alphabetical ORDER

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have problem. I must count the frequency of the elements in a list and I must print these element in alphabetical ORDER. The task is :https://1drv.ms/i/s!AqbJai99OU_ejy-jF_wOYaQCFjHR

I use this way:

```
**>>>from collections import Counter
>>>text= "he he he he she it she it she it and and and "
>>>words=text.split()
>>>counter=Counter(words)
>>>top_three=counter.most_common(4)
>>>top_three.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
>>>print(top_three)**
```

But I when I do test run I have this problem :https://1drv.ms/i/s!AqbJai99OU_ejzBadWfydEv6oGpa

I know that I must use count_words function but I don't know how to do it. 
If you know please write to me :D

Comment: Please, paste the error here, [do not link images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: `from filename_that_has_count_words_defined import count_words`. You haven't imported the `count_words` function and you've used it somewhere, that's what your error is telling you.

Comment: Task is : Count words in Python
Problem
Implement a function count_words() in Python that takes as input a string s and a number n, and returns the n most frequently-occuring words in s. The return value should be a list of tuples - the top n words paired with their respective counts [(<word>, <count>), (<word>, <count>), ...], sorted in descending count order.

Comment: You can assume that all input will be in lowercase and that there will be no punctuations or other characters (only letters and single separating spaces). In case of a tie (equal count), order the tied words alphabetically.

E.g.:

print count_words("betty bought a bit of butter but the butter was bitter",3)
Output:

Comment: [('butter', 2), ('a', 1), ('betty', 1)]
Instructions
This is a Python programming exercise. A simple code editor will open up in the next node. Follow the instructions in the template code provided to complete the exercise (look for "TODO"s).

You can execute your program using the Test Run button. Output is shown below the editor area.

Comment: ERROR IS Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vm_main.py", line 33, in <module>
    import main
  File "/tmp/vmuser_zuswxngeua/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import studentMain
  File "/tmp/vmuser_zuswxngeua/studentMain.py", line 4, in <module>
    from count_words import count_words, test_run
ImportError: cannot import name count_words

Answer (score 0):

This is an easier way to get the count for similar words and sort them.

```
text = 'he he he he she it she it she it and and and'

wordlist = text.split()
wordlist.sort()

wordfreq = []
for w in wordlist:
    wordfreq.append(wordlist.count(w))
    print(w)

print()
print("String\n" + text +"\n")
print("List\n" + str(wordlist) + "\n")
print("Frequencies\n" + str(wordfreq) + "\n")
```

@D.Tarik Code below does the work as you want. Please accept the answer if you think it is correct and has helped you.

```
def count_word(text):

    wordlist = text.split()
    wordlist.sort()
    my_list = []

    for i in wordlist:
        if i not in my_list:
            word_count = wordlist.count(i)
            my_list.append((i,word_count))
    print(set(my_list))


count_word('he he he he she it she it she it and and and')
```

Output:

```
{('he', 4), ('and', 3), ('it', 3), ('she', 3)}
```

Comment: Because  
Task is : Count words in Python Problem Implement a function count_words() in Python that takes as input a string s and a number n, and returns the n most frequently-occuring words in s. The return value should be a list of tuples - the top n words paired with their respective counts [(<word>, <count>), (<word>, <count>), ...], sorted in descending count order.

Comment: You can assume that all input will be in lowercase and that there will be no punctuations or other characters (only letters and single separating spaces). In case of a tie (equal count), order the tied words alphabetically. E.g.: print count_words("betty bought a bit of butter but the butter was bitter",3) Output:

Comment: [('butter', 2), ('a', 1), ('betty', 1)] Instructions This is a Python programming exercise. A simple code editor will open up in the next node. Follow the instructions in the template code provided to complete the exercise (look for "TODO"s). You can execute your program using the Test Run button. Output is shown below the editor area.

Comment: But error is ERROR IS Traceback (most recent call last): File "vm_main.py", line 33, in <module> import main File "/tmp/vmuser_zuswxngeua/main.py", line 2, in <module> import studentMain File "/tmp/vmuser_zuswxngeua/studentMain.py", line 4, in <module> from count_words import count_words, test_run ImportError: cannot import name count_words

Comment: And I must use count_words function

Comment: @D.Tarik From your comments it feels like this is a homework exercise. The code above gives you all the information that is needed (in your comments) What are you stuck on ?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to write this code because I just started learning python and I know writing only this code above  This exercise will give me scholarship for January 2017 and  I don't have time to learn python for this exercise which I must finish for 28,10,2016 but to January I can learn python very well. Please help me if you know :D

Comment: I can learn python very well to January. 
please help me if you know :D